# Ran a wrong sed command. All source code files messed up

Tags: linux, sed

So basically, I ran this:

```
sed -i '/s/icap_infos/icap_servers/g' *
```

instead of this:

```
sed -i 's/icap_infos/icap_servers/g' *
```

Notice the leading forward slash before 's' in the command?

Now all my source files have a weird text string scattered across the whole file. How do I fix this?

Comment: For the future: Use a version control system for your source file, ALWAYS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/s/` is a regular expression address that matches any line containing an `s` character. In GNU sed, `itext` is an extension to the standard

```
i\
text
```

that **i**nserts `text` after the addressed line. So your command inserted text `cap_infos/icap_servers/g` before any line containing an `s`.

Assuming your original files contained no such files you should be able to reverse it using

```
sed -i.old '\:^cap_infos/icap_servers/g$:d' *
```

to **d**elete lines matching `cap_infos/icap_servers/g` exactly. Note the use of alternate delimiter `:` (introduced by `\:`) since the pattern itself contains the default delimiter `/`. The current files will be backed up with suffix `.old` in case it doesn't work and you need to try something different.

In future get into the habit of dry-running sed commands **without** `-i` first and/or making backups using `-i.bak` instead of plain `-i`.

Answer (score 5):

The `/s/` is interpreted as an address, so the next command will only be applied for lines containing an `s`. This next command is `i`, inserting the following text, namely `cap_infos/icap_servers/g`.

Three things to do:

1. As it is unlikely that you have intentionally lines with only `cap_infos/icap_servers/g` in it, you can delete them with `sed '/^cap_infos\/icap_servers\/g$/d'` (again, you *address* what to `d`elete)
2. Do the intended change
3. Learn always to check the changes before using `-i` option in future